# How to display grouped data collection in FlexLayout of Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to bind **grouped** data collection to a FlexLayout, like in *CollectionView* which has *'IsGrouped'* property. Is there anything like that in FlexLayout? Currently, I can bind non-grouped collection of data using *BindableLayout* as like below

```
<FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
                    Wrap="Wrap"
                    JustifyContent="Start"
                    AlignItems="Start"
                    AlignContent="Start">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                            
                             <Frame WidthRequest="154" Padding="0" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True">
                                 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                      <Image Source="{Binding Image}" WidthRequest="130" HeightRequest="130" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                      <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="RobotoMedium" TextColor="#001B48" FontSize="8"></Label>
                                 </StackLayout>                            
                             </Frame>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

The reason for choosing FlexLayout is the necessity of making my app looks good in landscape mode too while listing out the data. Now I need to list out grouped collection of data in same way.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

In your case if you want to display data collection with group , you could use **ListView(or CollectionView)** and set the ViewCell with  **BindableLayout** .

**Sample code**

```
<ListView //...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 
               <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"
                    Wrap="Wrap"
                    JustifyContent="Start"
                    AlignItems="Start"
                    AlignContent="Start">
                    //...
               </FlexLayout>

            </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView >
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64569433/xamarin-listview-of-listlist/64569759#64569759) that you can have a refer .

#### Option 2

If you don't want to use ListView , you can also set the BindableLayout in the `DataTemplate` of another BindableLayout . Make sure that you set the correct path of ItemsSource .

Comment: I tried option 1. But the data didn't shown up. Is it possible to list out the grouped data collections only with FlexLayout?

Comment: I think it caused by you set the wrong path of data source . You could share your sample to github and I will test it on my side .